# Margin problems when printing PDF using LPR on OS X

Tags: macos, pdf, cups, lpr

I'm printing a PDF document using `LPR` on OS X, to a Canon MP190 printer.
When printing the same document (Letter paper size) from the Preview app, the margins are correct.
When printing using `LPR`, the document is printed, but it is offset (it is 3/4" lower on the page).
I have tried changing all possible options using `lpoptions`, but none of them affect scaling or offset.
I made sure to set `-o media=Letter` instead of the a4 page size option.
Some options actually get ignored completely (it still prints color when `CNIJGrayScale` is set to 1 or 2), but others are respected, such as `Resolution=600x600dpi`

Comment: Looks like I had missed one printer-specific option:
`-o PageSize=na-letter`

That fixed it.

Comment: Once you can, please post your answer below by using the **answer your question** button, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed one printer-specific option: `-o PageSize=na-letter`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the command `lpoptions -l` to show all the printer-specific options for your printer, and then pick the correct page size for your printer. In the case of my printer, the correct option was `8.5x11`.

```
lp -o PageSize=8.5x11 -o media=Letter example.pdf
```